# É possível filtrar uma base em SQL com base em uma lista de valores?

Tags: sql

Em pandas, quando quero filtrar um `DataFrame` com base em uma lista de valores, faço:

```py
valores=[15,17,22]
df=df[[k in valores for k in df.mpg]]
```

Em SQL eu sei que posso obter o mesmo resultado com o seguinte código:

```sql
SELECT * FROM 'dataset.table1'
WHERE mpg=15
OR mpg=17
OR mpg=22
```

O problema desse método é que se a lista de valores for muito grande eu preciso escrever `OR` centenas ou até milhares de vezes.

Existe uma forma mais sucinta de fazer essa query no SQL usando uma lista como em pandas?

P.S: No exemplo do pandas usei o *example dataset* [auto.csv](https://github.com/lucascr91/playground/blob/master/auto.csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O operador [`IN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_(SQL)#IN) testa múltiplos valores em uma lista de elementos entre parênteses.

O seu exemplo ficaria:

```sql
SELECT * FROM 'dataset.table1' WHERE mpg IN (15, 17, 22)
```

Também é possível usar o resultado de um `SELECT` como valor:

```sql
SELECT * FROM numeros WHERE num IN (SELECT num FROM pares)
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/he4Ee7)